# Remove duplicates standing one after another in array

Tags: java, arraylist

I can't realize how to proper loop for delete all duplicates standing one by one in array.
For example, I have a next array list :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(0);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(0);
}
```

And the result should be :

```
{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}
```

I was trying to do this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < integers.size(); j++){
                if (integers.get(i) == integers.get(j)){
                    integers.remove(integers.get(i));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

but I don't want to loop by every "j" when "i" didn't increase.

Can you give please an advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a single loop by keeping track of the last value read from the list:

```
int last = integers.get(0);
for(int i = 1; i < integers.size(); i++) {
    if (integers.get(i).equals(last)) {
        integers.remove(i);
        i--;
    } else {
        last = integers.get(i);
    }
}
```

P.S. `integers.remove(integers.get(i));` is wrong anyway, since it removes the first occurrence of `integers.get(i)` from the `List` and you should remove the current occurrence. Therefore you should remove by index and not by value.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single loop

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < integers.size() - 1 ; ++i) {
    if (integers[i].equals(integers[i + 1])) {
        integers.remove(i + 1);
        --i;
    }
}
```

If you have a match remove the duplicate and decrease the iteration variable as `remove` shifts the elements in the `ArrayList` left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterator:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = integers.iterator();
int last = it.next();
int current;

while( it.hasNext())
{
    current = it.next();
    if( current == last)
    {
        it.remove();
    }
    else
    {
        last = current;
    }
}
```